# How to call a groovy method using command line?

Tags: groovy

I am new to groovy. I have written a groovy shared library which is getting called by Jenkinsfile. However, I want to echo or print `pipeline strategy:` inside the method without waiting for Jenkins to call it. I am using IntelliJ IDE. Below is the code block. How do I manually call `def call(Map config = [:])` method from command line. This would save a lot of time if I first run locally in my system to make sure everything works well.

```
def call(Map config = [:]) {

    pipeline {
        defaults = [
                'pipelineStrategy'          : 'deployOnly',
                'buildSystem'               : 'maven',
                'autoDeploy'                : false,
                'hbbEnv'                    : 'dev',
                'hbbToken'                  : 'K8S_DEV_NS_TOKEN'
        ] + config

        echo "pipeline strategy:"

        switch (defaults.get('pipelineStrategy')) {
            case 'deployOnly':
                xxxxKubernetesPipeline(defaults, env)
                break
        }
    }
}
```

Below is the output I get in the IntelliJ IDE. Why isn't it echoing `pipeline strategy:`.
[image]

Comment: What is it that you want to happen as a result of that code executing from the command line?

Comment: I would like to echo or print the output of some variables and make sure that my groovy code is running fine. Once it is running fine then I will call these groovy methods using the Jenkinsfile.

Comment: Can you added content to the question indicating specifically what you want written to stdout and indicate where that information is coming from?

Comment: I just want to echo `pipeline strategy` inside the method.